# jQuery autocomplete как настроить?

Tags: json, jquery-ui, asp.net-core

Пытаюсь настроить JQuery Autocomplete, написал такой код:

```
$("#name_input").autocomplete({
        source: 'Home/MessageHandler',
        minLength: 1,
        select: function (event, ui) {
            log("Selected: " + ui.item.value);
        }
    });
});
```

И вот такой контроллер (использую ASP .Net Core):

```
public JsonResult MessageHandler()
{
    string result = "[{label:'string1',value:'string2'},{label:'string3',value:'string4'}]";

    return Json(result);
}
```

Если обратиться на прямую к контроллеру: http://localhost:3140/Home/MessageHandler
то все ок я получаю строку:

```
[{label:'string1',value:'string2'},{label:'string3',value:'string4'}]
```

Но если вводить запрос в инпут к которому подключено событие autocomplit, автокомплит **не появляется**, а в строке input появляется иконка загрузки которая больше не пропадает от туда(см. скрин3)
Прилагаю скрины ответа от сервера:

### **Заголовки:**

[image: Ответ от сервера]

### **Ответ сервера**

[image: Ответ от сервера2]

### **Иконка которая не пропадает**

[image: Строка инпут с иконкой которая не пропадает]

Answer (score 1):

Проблема была в том что контроллер отдавал не правильный json,
переписал так:

```
public IActionResult MessageHandler()
{

           var result = new[] { @"ActionScript", "AppleScript", "Asp", "BASIC", "C", "C++",
                                "Clojure", "COBOL", "ColdFusion", "Erlang","Fortran", "Groovy","Haskell",
                                "Java", "JavaScript", "Lisp", "Perl", "PHP", "Python","Ruby", "Scala", "Scheme" };

            return Json(result);
}
```

И все стало ок
Теперь ответ от сервера выглядит так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если кто подскажет где собака порылась будут благодарен.